# Feynman rules for four fermions theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, fermions

Consider a 4-fermion theory like:
$$\mathcal{L} = \bar{\psi}(i \partial_{\mu} \gamma^{\mu}  - m) \psi + G (\bar{\psi} \psi)^2$$
In Maggiore's book it is said this theory is used as an effective theory of Yukawa lagrangian when the energies are much lower than the mass of the scalar propagator. It is further said that the fisrt order amplitude of fermion-antifermion scattering is given by: $$i\mathcal{M} = iG [\bar{v}(p_1) u(p_2) \bar{u}(p'_2) v (p'_1)]$$ where the primed impulse are those of the outgoing particles. 
[image]
Now this is clear if one imagine to somehow shrink the scalar propagator in the Yukawa Feynman diagram up to a point and approximate in the proper way the Yukawa amplitude: i.e. forgets the $p^2$ in the denominator of the propagators. However its not clear to me this is the correct and formal expression for the amplitude of the 4-fermion theory. Can someone give me some elucidation?

Comment: How about Taylor expanding the propagator in terms of $\epsilon = p^2  / M^2$? or integrating out the scalar from the UV theory? etc

Comment: You seem to be using this four fermion theory just as a teaching tool but be careful that if you want to use it in realistic computations: you need to put the correct Standard Model vertices, a explained in this former [Q&A](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/358431/why-are-c-v-are-c-a-in-the-four-fermi-lagrangian-left-unspecified/358441#358441).

Comment: I do indeed, my question is actually kind of unrelated to the Fermi theory and is only about abstract four fermion interaction.